# How can I have a footer with 3 blocks of links?

Tags: magento2, footer

I currently made 3 "Link Blocks" and added them as widgets to my footer. The CSS was messed up and the block were NOT side by side aligned. Then, I added "display:flex" to ".links" div class. Now the Footer looks great and is side by side (not in mobile tho).

[image]

The Problem now is, there are multiple div classes called ".links", so they also have the css property "display:flex". This messes up some things like the image down below.

[image]

If someone could help me with this problem, I would be very very happy!

Comment: Is there a parent container for the footer? then you could simply add a css line (i.e.) `div.footer .links { display: flex; }` to the css file, then it will be only applied to the links in the footer.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same problem in magento 2.1.0,
I simply changed the css and it worked:
        .footer.content .links{display:flex;}

Also, I gave the class=footerlinks to the unordered list created in each block and added the css
                  .footer.links {display: block !important;}